# A query to list the names of all tables that contain a column with a specific name

Tags: sql-server

I have a database called `Database1` that contains a large number of tables. I am trying to identify all the tables that have a column called `Order Number`, but going through each table manually will take a long time.

Is it possible to execute a query that returns all names of tables that have a column with a specific name?

I tried this, but it didn't recognise `Database1`, nor `column`:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Database1 WHERE column = 'Order Number'
```

Comment: mysql != sql-server, pick one

Comment: @Tanner (off-topic): But both questions are about SQL. Therefore `!=` should be `<>`. ;-)

Comment: @stakx I think you'll find both work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20505 in sql server at least

Comment: @stakx No worries ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following query you can get list of tables that have column named 'Order Number':

```
SELECT Schema_name(t.schema_id), 
       Object_name(t.object_id) 
FROM   sys.columns c 
       INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
               ON t.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE  c.name = 'Order Number'
```

and by using following query you can get records of above table:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue NVARCHAR(max) = '' 

SELECT @ReturnValue = @ReturnValue + 'SELECT TOP(100) * FROM [' 
                      + Schema_name(t.schema_id) + '].[' 
                      + Object_name(t.object_id) + '] ' + Char(10) 
                      + Char(13) 
FROM   sys.columns c 
       INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
               ON t.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE  c.name = 'Order Number' 

PRINT @ReturnValue -- Inorder to check your query 

EXEC(@ReturnValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    use Database1
    SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
       WHERE column_name = 'Order Number'
```

Comment: It would be better to explain this answer.

Comment: Explanation: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/179/sql-server-informationschema-views/

Comment: And what happens if that website goes away?

Comment: Your answer should include the relevant details of that link, no website lasts forever.